# How to make comparisons of a needle in a haystack more efficient

Tags: php, performance, mysqli, foreach, strpos

I've been struggling to make the following piece of code more efficient.

In short;

I've got a database with titles and descriptions. The database will average on 10000 texts. I want to search compare these texts by splitting the text with 'mb_split' and then loop through all other texts to compare if the word exists. Depending on how many comparisons were made, I want to write the article numbers to another table in that database.

The following code works and does the trick, but it takes a really long time to finish and uses a lot of resources. I can't seem to find a way to compare these texts more efficiently.

```
function compareArticle() {
  include '../include/write.php';
  $readNewsQuery = "select title,text,articleid,name from texts";
  $readNews = $dbwrite->query($readNewsQuery);

  if ($readNews) {
    //Fetch mysql data as an array
    $news = $readNews->fetch_all(MYSQLI_NUM);
      // Start foreach to read every article once
      foreach ($news as $item) {
        echo $item[2].'<br />';
        // Start another foreach to loop through the articles to compare with
        foreach ($news as $compare) {
          $strippedWords = mb_split(' +', $item[0]);
          $count = 0;
          $compareString = "";
          $compareString .= $compare[0];
          $compareString .= $compare[1];
          $compareString = strtolower($compareString);
          // Start yet another foreach to loop through the words
          foreach ($strippedWords as $word) {
            // I only want to count the words that are longer than 4 characters
            if (strlen($word) > 4) {
              $woord = strtolower($word);
              if (strpos($compareString, $word) && $compare[2] != $item[2]) {
                $count++;
              }
            }
          }
          if ($count > 5) {
            echo $count.'<br />';
            //Insert action to write comparison to database (item[2] and compare[2])
          }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

What I'd really like to know;  Can I be more efficient? Could I use less loops, or is there an easier way to search the array? If I can be more efficient, could someone give me a nudge in the right direction?

EDIT:
It might be useful to know what data I retrieve and what I want to write to another table:

texts-database is set up to include

```
| article id | title | text | sourcename
```

I compare the words in a title with the words of title and text combined for all other articles. If they match enough, I want to write both article id's to another table:

```
| id | original article id | compared article id |
```

Comment: Use `LIKE` or `REGEXP` directly in the sql.

Comment: Yea, funny note @DavidLemon , I started off just using MySQL to gather most of the data, and that seems to go quite a bit faster. It caused some problems in combination with my cronjobs and I expected PHP arrays to be faster than the mysql queries I shot at MySQL.   That didn't end up to be true.   I'll be looking into your suggestion, as I am a 100% sure I can make my scripts a lot more efficient using some more advanced MySQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

Once you loop through a news item, you no longer need to compare any other news items to it, for example, if news item 1 didn't match the other 50 news items then when you start checking news item 2 you already know that it doesn't match news item 1.

So instead of looping through the news items twice, you can start your second loop on the current index +1 (you don't need to compare the current news item with itself) of your first news article loop.

Edit: Heres an example loop:

**Optimized Loop:**

```
$matches = array();
$a = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25 ];
$count = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($a); ++$i) {
    for ($j = $i+1; $j < count($a); ++$j) {
        if ($a[$i] == $a[$j]) {
            array_push($matches, "$i, $j");
        }
        $count++; 
    }
}
echo "Optimized n loops: $count\n";
echo 'Matches: ' . count($matches);

// Output
// Optimized n loops: 435
// Matches: 5
```

**Un-optimized Loop**

```
$matches = array();
$count = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($a); ++$i) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($a); ++$j) {
        if ($a[$i] == $a[$j]) {
            array_push($matches, "$i, $j");
        }
        $count++; 
    }
}
$matches = array_unique($matches); // Dedupe
echo "Un-optimized n loops: $count\n";
echo 'Matches: ' . count($matches);

// Output
// Un-optimized n loops: 900
// Matches: 40
```

The unoptimized loop includes a lot of duplicate matches (index 1 matches index 5, index 5 matches index 1)

Comment: Although I admittedly didn't think about this solution, it isn't 100% true. The comparisson starts with words only from the title of article 1. The words from this title are compared to the title and the text of the next articles.


This means that a word that is available in article 1 and not in the title of article 1 will never trigger if it compares to the title of article 2. 


I do find this solution interesting enough to drop my texts and see how big of a differense this makes.  Thanks for the suggestion! :)

Answer (score 0):

I've executed a lot of tests and made a few changes to my script and now know what the biggest culprit was.

Original case:

- Sample size of 10.000;
- Execution time: over 600 seconds (ran into max execution time).

Test case:

- Completely stripped down version of the original
- Sample size of 1000;
- Execution time: 24 seconds.

**What made the biggest difference?**

The biggest difference was changing the location of the following line:

```
$strippedWords = mb_split(' +', $item[0]);
```

I moved that line to the first loop instead of the second. This way the title from the first loop only gets split once every 1000 items instead of 1000 times every 1000 items. I measured the differences in time:

- mb_split in the second loop:

Total execution time in seconds: 162.17704296112

- mb_split in the first loop:

Total execution time in seconds: 24.564566135406

That's an amazingly huge difference. I'm guessing mb_split isn't the easiest thing for PHP to do. Putting mb_split in the wrong part of my code made the script almost 7 times slower :|

**strtolower()**

After that result, I was curious what differences I could make changing the location of other text modifiers. So, I took strtolower() and put that, where possible, in the first loop as well.

- strtolower() in second loop:

Total execution time in seconds: 44.315208911896

- strtolower() in first loop:

Total execution time in seconds: 37.129139900208

Although this difference is a lot smaller, it's still a notable difference.

**A possible other cause**

I am not sure -- as I don't currently have the time to test this -- if this is completely true, but while testing a few cases I found my browser was acting up. When I told PHP to output a lot of information to my browser, the scripts felt like they would run longer and the browser would stop showing information after a while, too.

If the occasion arrises and I have some spare time left, I'll be testing this theory and try to see if my browser can actually screw with the duration of my PHP scripts. I can't seem to find a logical reason as to why it would impact the duration of my PHP script, as I expect the browser to just crash and my PHP script to continue working server sided... but the thought crossed my mind a few times.

**anyway, here's the new script**

```
function compareArticle() {
  //For timing my script
  $time_start = microtime(true);

  include '../include/write.php';
  $readNewsQuery = "select title,text,articleid,name,datetoday from texts";
  $readNews = $dbwrite->query($readNewsQuery);
  $dateToday = date("Y-m-d");

  if ($readNews) {
    //Fetch mysql data as an array
    $news = $readNews->fetch_all(MYSQLI_NUM);
  }

  foreach ($news as $item) {
    // Decrease the sample pool
    if ($item[4] != $dateToday) {
      continue;
    }
    $strippedWords = strtolower($item[0]);
    $strippedWords = mb_split(' +', $strippedWords);

    // Start another foreach to loop through the articles to compare with
      foreach ($news as $compare) {

        $compareString = "";
        $compareString .= $compare[0];
        $compareString .= $compare[1];

        $count = 0;

        // Start yet another foreach to loop through the words
        foreach ($strippedWords as $word) {
          // I only want to count the words that are longer than 4 characters
          if (strlen($word) > 4) {

            if (strpos(strtolower($compareString), $word)) {
              $count++;
            }
          }
        }
```